# Equivalence of limits?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be two sequences. Is it always right to say that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-b_n)=0 \iff \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$$
?

Comment: Provided $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n) \neq 0$

Comment: It would be more convincing to think that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n - b_n| = 0 \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_n|}{|b_n|} = 1 $$ But this still isn't true.

Comment: Counterexamples: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434055/show-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-fraca-nb-n-1-implies-lim-n-righta, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571454/is-this-property-of-two-sequences-a-n-and-b-n-possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have shown this isn't true in general. In their examples, the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ either both tend to $0$ or to $\infty$. What happens in other cases?

Suppose that $\lim b_n = L$ is finite and $\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$. Then,
$$
\left| a_n - b_n \right|
= |b_n| \left| \frac{a_n - b_n}{b_n} \right|
= |b_n| \left| \frac{a_n}{b_n} - 1 \right|
\to |L| \cdot 0 = 0
$$
Thus, $\lim (a_n-b_n) = 0.$

In the same way, if $\lim b_n = L \neq 0$ and $\lim (a_n-b_n) = 0$ then
$$
\left| \frac{a_n}{b_n} - 1 \right|
= \left| \frac{a_n-b_n}{b_n} \right|
= \frac{1}{|b_n|} \left| a_n-b_n \right|
\to \frac{1}{|L|} \cdot 0 = 0
$$
Thus, $\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1.$

Therefore, if $\lim b_n$ exists and is neither zero or infinite, then we do have equivalence. In this case, of course $\lim a_n = \lim b_n = L.$

Answer (score 7):

No. Let $a_n=n$, and $b_n=n+1.$

Comment: This quotient still converges to 1 ...

Comment: @DionelJaime um what? We have $a_n-b_n$ converges to $-1$ and $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ converges to $1$.

Comment: Ahh I didn't notice his double implication, sorry ...

Answer (score 5):

$$a_n=\frac 1{n^2}, b_n =\frac{1}{n}  $$

Then $$\lim (a_n-b_n)=0$$ 
But $$\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim \frac{1}{n}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

If only the world was that simple.

Let $a_n = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{2^{n}}$

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n=\frac{\sin{n}}{n}, b_n=\frac{1}{n}$, then:
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (a_n-b_n)=0,$$
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\sin{n},$$
which does not exist.